# List of machine learning classifiers that naturally assume data in normal distribution

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, data-transformation, data-preprocessing

I have searched about this question but no answer really made it comprehensive. To my knowledge, linear regression and most clustering algorithms naturally have the assumption that data need to be in normal distribution for better outcomes. My question is about other classifiers like SVM, NN, KNN, ... etc. Can someone provide us a good answer or direct me to an existing post that elaborate this?

Thank you

Comment: Adding to stans' comment, Gaussian Naive Bayes (the most common NB classifier used for continuous features) also assumes normality of the features.

Comment: @stans: [do you want to post your comments as an answer?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/1352)

Comment: @Stephan Kolassa: sure, if you think they are exhaustive enough to qualify as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cannot agree to this. Linear regression is statistically efficient if the *residuals* are Gaussian. The whole data do not have to be Gaussian. Even that condition (normality of residuals) is unnecessary if the sample size is big... Except for a few degenerate cases, most popular clustering algorithms do not require normality.

Regarding classification: to the best of my knowledge, only Linear Discriminant Analysis and Quadratic Discriminant Analysis are derived under the assumption of normality. Still, they perform quite well in many other settings.

Comment: Thank you! Better to have a short answer than no answer at all. Anyone who has a better answer can post it.